# Getting Keys Within Range/Finding Nearest Neighbor From Dictionary Keys Stored As Tuples

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary which has coordinates as keys. They are by default in 3 dimensions, like `dictionary[(x,y,z)]=values`, but may be in any dimension, so the code can't be hard coded for 3.

I need to find if there are other values within a certain radius of a new coordinate, and I ideally need to do it without having to import any plugins such as numpy.

My initial thought was to split the input into a cube and check no points match, but obviously that is limited to integer coordinates, and would grow exponentially slower (radius of 5 would require 729x the processing), and with my initial code taking at least a minute for relatively small values, I can't really afford this.

I heard finding the nearest neighbor may be the best way, and ideally, cutting down the keys used to a range of +- a certain amount would be good, but I don't know how you'd do that when there's more the one point being used.
Here's how I'd do it with my current knowledge:

```
dimensions = 3
minimumDistance = 0.9

#example dictionary + input
dictionary[(0,0,0)]=[]
dictionary[(0,0,1)]=[]
keyToAdd = [0,1,1]

closestMatch = 2**1000
tooClose = False

for keys in dictionary:

    #calculate distance to new point
    originalCoordinates = str(split( dictionary[keys], "," ) ).replace("(","").replace(")","")
    for i in range(dimensions):
        distanceToPoint = #do pythagors with originalCoordinates and keyToAdd

    #if you want the overall closest match
    if distanceToPoint < closestMatch:
        closestMatch = distanceToPoint

    #if you want to just check it's not within that radius
    if distanceToPoint < minimumDistance:
        tooClose = True
        break
```

However, performing calculations this way may still run very slow (it must do this to millions of values). I've searched the problem, but most people seem to have simpler sets of data to do this to. If anyone can offer any tips I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you need to determine IF there are any keys within a given radius of a particular point.  Thus, you only need to scan the keys, computing the distance of each to the point until you find one within the specified radius.  (And if you do comparisons to the *square* of the radius, you can avoid the square roots needed for the actual distance.)

One optimization would be to sort the keys based on their "Manhattan distance" from the point (that is, add the component offsets), since the Euclidean distance will never be less than this.  This would avoid some of the more expensive calculations (though I don't think you need and trigonometry).

If, as you suggest later in the question, you need to handle multiple points, you can obviously process each individually, or you could find the center of those points and sort based on that.

Comment: Thanks, though by component offsets, if the key to add was (1,1,1), do you mean the manhattan distance to point (0,0,0) would be 3? That sounds a good method to use, but would the lowest manhatten distance always relate to the shortest length? I can imagine the point (3,3,3) is closer than (8,0,0) to (0,0,0), so is there a way to account for this?

Comment: @Peter: Manhattan distance will give an upper bound on the Euclidean distance, but is cheaper/faster to compute.  So if the Manhattan distance is within your radius, the actual one must be as well.

Comment: Ah ok thanks, I just did a test of 15 million loops with a few methods, it results in 12 seconds with proper trig, 9 seconds with trig minus the square root, and 7 seconds with the manhatten method. I think the further work that would need to be done with the lowest manhatten values (eg. add them to a list and apply the trig) would probably knock the execution time up again, so currently it looks like doing trigonometry without the square root is the best bet for now :)

Comment: @Peter: I'm curious what trigonometry you need here; I didn't think any was needed for computing a distance, just addition/subtraction, squares & square-roots (the latter can be avoided if you only need to do comparisons, and not have the actual distance).

Comment: Ah sorry, I initially incorrectly wrote trigonometry without realising it was just pythagoras in 3D, and I didn't give it any more thought after so kept using the word haha. I'll update the main question, though if you can add the second part of your comment to the answer, I'll click accept on it, as the squares without square roots are by far the best method :)